# React-Bootstrap not reading my active class

Tags: sass, progressive-web-apps, react-bootstrap

I'm studying React-Bootstrap and Magento PWA using Sass. I made a slider with a folder structure like this :

- Slider (folder)

  - index.js (file)
  - slider.js (file)
  - slider.scss (file)

The following code for the slider.js file

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import {
       Carousel,
       CarouselItem,
       Image
} from 'react-bootstrap';

import { mergeClasses } from '@magento/venia-ui/lib/classify';
import defaultClasses from './slider.scss';

import BannerHome from '$src/assets/images/slider/banner-homepage.png';

const Slider = props => {
const classes = mergeClasses(defaultClasses, props.classes);
  
  return (
    <div className={classes.sliderBox}>
        <Carousel className={classes.sliderInside} interval={900} >
          <CarouselItem>
            <Image
              src={BannerHome} />
          </CarouselItem >
          <CarouselItem>
            <Image
              src={BannerHome} />
          </CarouselItem>
          <CarouselItem>
            <Image
              src={BannerHome} />
          </CarouselItem>
        </Carousel>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Slider;
```

and the following snippet of my scss code

```
.sliderBox {
margin-bottom: 10px;
> .sliderInside {
    > ol {
        bottom: -20px;
        > li {
            opacity: 1;
            &.active {
                background-color: $blue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here's a screenshot of the results

[image: slider]

the problem is the carousel-indicators

where should the active li element be blue but the active class is not found.

[image: active class]

How to apply color to the li element with the active class?

Comment: `:active` only activates when you're actually clicking on the icon. I think you'd prefer to use `:hover`, or set the `li` to be a background of blue instead. This problem also needs more clarification because we dont see any styling for the indicators.

Comment: hi @Andrew not :active selector but .active class. like in the picture I attached.